# Run multiple functions in background C# WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have multiple functions which needs to be run in background.
These functions basically reads RSS XML feeds and save feed data to online database, the problem is that the whole application get stuck when these functions are being executed.

All I want it should not stuck, whole application should behave normal way.

I tried background worker (may be I've implemented it in wrong way)

Here is code:

```
BackgroundWorker bw;
    public HomePage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        bw = new BackgroundWorker();
        bw.WorkerReportsProgress = true;
        bw.WorkerSupportsCancellation = true;
        bw.DoWork += bw_DoWork;
        DispatcherTimer d = new System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherTimer();
        d.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        d.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 15, 0);
        d.Start();
    }
private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.bw.IsBusy)
        {
            bw.RunWorkerAsync();
        }
    }
void bw_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        DoWork();
    }
void DoWork()
    {
        try
        {
            System.Threading.Thread thread = new System.Threading.Thread(new System.Threading.ThreadStart(
        delegate()
        {
            this.Dispatcher.Invoke(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority.Normal, new Action(
                delegate()
                {
                    SaveRSSFeed(); // This is the function, and this function call other functions
                }
            ));
        }
        ));
            thread.IsBackground = true;
            thread.Start();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "", MessageBoxButton.OK, MessageBoxImage.Error);
        }
    }
```

**Note:** These functions are automatically called after 15 minutes.
Please help me, where I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your thread delegates **all** of its work back to the UI thread (`this.Dispatcher.Invoke`). Only access to UI elements needs to be "invoked".

Besides, it's a bit unusual to start a thread from a `BackgroundWorker`.

Comment: Thanks mate, its working perfectly with your and Sheridan's help :)

Answer (score 2):

As @JeffRSon has correctly noted, you have *not* implemented your `BackgroundWorker` correctly... when using a `BackgroundWorker`, we let *it* take care of starting and running `Thread`s... that *its* job, *not yours*. The idea is to simplify the use of `Thread`s. Try using this as your `DoWork` method instead:

```
private void DoWork()
{
    SaveRSSFeed(); // This is the function, and this function call other functions
}
```

Please take a look at the [`BackgroundWorker` Class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN for more help with correctly implementing it.